# .htaccess mask on current website

Tags: htaccess

I've got a website on a FTP, mysite, on which I have :

```
/index.php which is my real site

/preprod/index.php, which is my pre-production website
```

I want to make the preprod website visible to any newcomer, but be able to enter a secret URL to access the real site

I've built the following .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule mysite.com/secret mysite/preprod/index.php [L,R=301]
Redirect /index.php /preprod/index.php
```

I've got a "404 error"

How could I correct my file ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this belongs on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)
Secondly, why do you even need any htaccess rules? Just have /index as the pre production site, then put your secret site in a separate folder. Or better still, you could create a subdomain for the secret site

Comment: Would you be able to answer if I posted it on SO ?

Comment: You will definitely get an answer on SO, but I still don't understand why you are bothering to use htaccess when you could simply just use real directories :)

Comment: Well, you are right, I shouldn't. But I wanna learn how to to this, then I'll decide :)